# Center alignment for both vertical and horizontal

Tags: html, vertical-alignment

I want to show an image in the center of a page with original size.

I tried the code below

```css
.container 
    {
    
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
        vertical-align: middle;
     }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <div class="container"><img src="1.png" alt="No Internet Connection" ></div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Vertical align elements in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/how-to-vertical-align-elements-in-a-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container 
    {
      display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
       height: 90vh;
     }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    
    <div class="container"><img src="1.png" alt="No Internet Connection" ></div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

You can use `display: flex;`. It's responsive and works great. After that I used `justify-content: center;` because of this it is horizontal in the center. And because of `align-items: center;` and `height: 90vh;` it is vertical centered

Comment: it is vertically not centered properly

Comment: @Sabuj what do you mean? If you are talking about the height you can change it

Comment: Actually i am making a html page for android webview.loadurl() function. When the html page load with image the image is slightly below the center of android screen.

Comment: @Sabuj you can change the height yourself, I would recommend you to use `vh` but you can also use `px`

Comment: @Sabuj check css units there are all units and look what is fine for you